# Adding a active class to all span within a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with 2 span as a link, I want to add active class on both span when mouse enters the container div i.e. fos-search-items

```
var $hover_element = $('.fos-search-items');
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find("span").addClass('fos-db-active');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find("span").removeClass('fos-db-active');
    })
```

Comment: You need to remove the `;` after the selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$hover_element` on event while `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`

**Option 1** [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dchzv2x0/3/)

```
var $hover_element = $('.fos-search-items');

$hover_element.mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find("span").addClass('fos-db-active');
});

$hover_element.mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find("span").removeClass('fos-db-active');
});
```

**Option 2** [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/dchzv2x0/4/)

Just remove the `;` after the `$('.fos-search-items')`

```
var $hover_element = $('.fos-search-items').mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).find("span").addClass('fos-db-active');
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).find("span").removeClass('fos-db-active');
    });
```

Comment: thanks, man, its working, but same code not working on my project any suggestion plz

Comment: if my code helps please do apprecation by upvote or accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var $hover_element = $('.fos-search-items');
 $hover_element.mouseenter(function() {
  $( this ).find( "span" ).addClass('fos-db-active');
  })

 $hover_element.mouseleave(function() {
  $( this ).find( "span" ).removeClass('fos-db-active');

  })
```

[**Working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/dchzv2x0/1/)

Comment: see the rory's comment.

Comment: I have seen it now but when I start to answer this was not available @Jai

Answer (score 0):

You have not attached the events correctly.`mouseenter` and `mouseleave` should be attached to DOM elements jquery object.Like this:

```
$('.fos-search-items').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find("span").addClass('fos-db-active');
})
$('.fos-search-items').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find("span").removeClass('fos-db-active');
})
```

also, you can rather use `.hover()` with two function argumenents for mousenter and mouseleave:

```
$('.fos-search-items').hover(function(){
   $(this).find('span').addClass('fos-db-active')
},function(){
   $(this).find('span').removeClass('fos-db-active')
});
```